# how to make a queue whose template argument is an abstract base class?

Tags: c++, c++11, queue, abstract-class

My program needs a FIFO queue to hold all of these events going. These events should be of different user-defined types, but the queue needs one template parameter. So I figured that I would use an abstract base class. Additionally, this also has the benefit of forcing the derived classes to have the function signatures I want.

However, when I try the following, I inspect elements of the queue via `std::queue::front`, but it doesn't let me call virtual functions of these elements.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>

class Base
{
public:
    virtual double returnNum() {};
};

class InfoChunk : public Base
{
private:
    double m_num;
public:
    InfoChunk(const double& arg) : m_num(arg) {};
    double returnNum() {return m_num;};
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    std::queue<Base> q;
    InfoChunk info(.2);
    q.push(info);
    while(!q.empty()){
        std::cout << q.front().returnNum() << "\n";
        q.pop();
    }    

    return 0;
}
```

This all compiles, but it prints `0` instead of `.2`. What's the deal here?

Comment: You can't store objects by value and expect polymorphic behavior. You have to store by (possibly smart) pointer. See also: [object slicing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing)

Comment: @IgorTandetnik this is related to something I just asked about the other day. Looks like this stuff isn't sinking in for me. Thanks for the help--I'll search for more general results that discuss the relationship between polymorphism and pointers

Comment: Also, your `Base` class isn't abstract as it implements all the functions. To be abstract it should have `= 0;` instead of the function body `{ }`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your base to be abstract, it requires at least on pure virtual function. Furthermore, the reason you code compiles is because `Base` is sliceable. This means that when derived is assigned to base, the derived portion is lost due to the fact that by default only the members of base are copied.

To achieve what you want, you need to use a queue of pointers (as a derived pointer automatically converts to a base pointer - polymorphically compatible), preferably a smart pointer like shared_ptr that already performs the necessary memory management for you.

The example code below achieves what you want.

```
#include <queue>
#include <memory>

struct Base
{
  virtual void foo() = 0;
  virtual ~Base(){}
};

struct Derived : Base
{
  void foo() override{}
};

int main() {

    std::queue<std::shared_ptr<Base>> xq;
    xq.push(std::make_shared<Derived>());
    Base& x = xq.back();
    xq.pop();
    return 0;
}
```

You could also have just used plain pointers, but this implies you would need to provide your own memory management (e.g):

```
int main() {

    std::queue<Base*> xq;
    xq.push(new Derived);
    Base* x = xq.back();
    xq.pop(); //Note: Dont delete before popping...
    delete x; //Or keep it

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: it isn't clear to me if `X` is the base class or derived class. I think I want something like `std::queue<std::shared_ptr<Xbase>> xq;` right? And for the line after that...how do I convert an already-made derived object to a (smart) pointer, pointing to the right type? The way you have it here it's kind of pushing a blank object onto the queue. Perhaps something like `xq.push(std::make_shared<X>(preExistingObjOfDerivedType));`

Comment: I've modified my example for clarity in your context. Please let me know if this is now clearer. You'll notice that Derived derives publicly from Base, but shared_ptr<Base> is used as polymorphic type in the queue. A normal Base* could also have been used, but that implies you have to add own memory management